# How can I set the value of a cell based on the larger of two sums?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

As the subject says, I need to set the value of a cell to the larger of two sums. It seems basic enough but so far I can't get it working.

For instance:

```
=SUM(B9 + B12)     178
=SUM(B10 + B11)     12
```

Is there a way to compare two sums and to conditionally set another cell's value?

Comment: Just for the record, syntax like `=SUM(B9 + B12)` is redundant and the SUM function does nothing of purpose. Use`=B9 + B12` or `=SUM(B9, B12)` to express a sum of two cells or `=SUM(B10:B11)` to sum a contiguous range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> =MAX(SUM(B9,B12),SUM(B10,B11))

If your SUM functions are already located in cells somewhere on your sheet, say maybe `A1 = SUM(B9,B12)` and `A2 = SUM(B10,B11)`, then you can just use

> =MAX(A1,A2)

Comment: Plus for being the only one to correct the SUM syntax. (where did B211 come from?)

Comment: @Jeeped From a special place, where all typos co-exist in harmony.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I overlooked the MAX function in the Excel reference docs.

Answer (score 1):

That what the `MAX` function is for. You don't necessarily need the `SUM` functions in this particular case (though it doesn't hurt).

```
=MAX(B9+B12, B10+B11)
```

If your `SUM` formulas are already in their own cells, just use the `MAX` function on those cells.